# Can the 3rd party apps be mirrored on Apple Tv?

Tags: appletv

Can Apple TV mirroring be used with all the apps on iOS device? If mirroring is turned on,
Can all the apps, including 3rd party apps be projected on the TV screen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes...   Works with my Iphone 4s and latest Apple TV

Comment: Just thought I might add.   It looks like third party apps can block this.   One example is my cable company that has an app to look at streamed programming.   It is blocked... rather inelegantly from streaming to apple TV.   It is the only apps so far that I have found that does not work.